# django through apache was working, now it's not

Tags: django

I'm not sure what changed. Fairly new to this.

apache conf file says:

> WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/django/projects/django.wsgi

The error log says:

> File does not exist: /var/www/django/projects/django.wsgi/

Not sure why it put the trailing slash there.

Comment: Hate to ask the proverbial "Is it plugged in" but does the file `/var/www/django/projects/django.wsgi` exist and is it accessible from the user Apache runs as?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by trial and error.

I had put in this line:

> SetHandler python-program

but when I took it out, it works again. I guess I don't understand this command.